# How to import data from csv file to the default Django User model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-import-export

I know there is an import-export package which allows us to import data from csv file to our own models by making changes in the admin.py file, but I am not able to do this if I want to import data from csv file to the default User model present in Django. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely want to write your own custom [Management Command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) for this job.

You can import the CSV data [easily with Tablib](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#importing-data).

In the management command you have complete access to your Django models. Then you just invoke your new command with `python manage.py <name_of_your_command>`!